# Locked out because of password

Tags: boot

Initially Ubuntu was set up, with the wrong keyboard.
I managed to change the keyboard, but didn't realize that my password would then no longer enter correctly. Consequently I'm locked out.
How can I now change the password ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Change a Forgotten User Password Without Booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831921/how-do-i-change-a-forgotten-user-password-without-booting)

Comment: I didn't get the line display that was suggested I should. If I could find an image of the Ubuntu French AZERTY keyboard, I could then see what the original keys were and transpose them to the current keyboard...

Comment: You mean an image like from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY ?

Comment: It needs to be the image of  the Ubuntu French AZERTY, as it would appear on a Dell XPS13 keyboard...