How do I reinstall Ubuntu
I recently discovered I couldn't log in to my admin account. So I went and tried to login to my sister's account but it couldn't work. We have the passwords on a piece of paper in a locked drawer so we did it over 20 times and we couldn't log into either accounts. So I want to reinstall Ubuntu but I can't login. What do I do to reinstall it. I have windows to use partition manager but is there another way as I have another data partition and when I first installed Ubuntu it got confused on which is which and ended up installing it on my data partition. I got some photos of partition manager available for you to look atFirst half of Boot manager
Second half of Boot Manager

https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass  https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password https://askubuntu.com/questions/831921/how-do-i-change-a-forgotten-user-password-without-booting any of these works w/o needing to reinstall. and make sure capslock is correctly set when typing passwords

You mention re-installing Ubuntu, but give no specifics. Ubuntu is available using the ubiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer and subiquity installers, where options vary. If you're talking about a Ubuntu that will use ubiquity or calamares installer I talk about it on an answer here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) but that may not help you if you're talking about using the ubuntu-desktop-installer or subiquity but you didn't specify any more than Ubuntu. Is encryption involved? (link doesn't cover encryption)

I believe Ubuntu desktop installer

Release details matter; if your system is online, the ubuntu-desktop-installer can upgrade and thus use a newer version than exists on your ISO, however if offline the version varies between releases. Ubuntu 23.04 & later used it; but 23.04 & 23.10 didn't use ubuntu-desktop-provision which made it different to later releases (issue I mention in my link with non-destructive re-instlal refers to problem in provision component)... You've not indicated what release so I can't help sorry.
